# Activity not moving to next activity when button click in android?

Tags: android, android-activity, imagebutton

I am trying to move from one activity to another activity by clicking to the `ImageButton`. But when I click to button, it doesn't move to the activity which I specify in the code, and even it does not throw an error. I'm not getting where is problem
Here is my code which calls next activity :

```
    package com.birthdayreminder;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ImageButton;
    import android.widget.TextView;

       public class Reminder extends Activity {

ImageButton view, add, edit;

TextView tvadd, tvedit, tvview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_reminder);

}

public void innicialize() {

    // assigning buttons
    view = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bView);
    add = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
    edit = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bEdit);

    // assign textview
    tvadd = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvAdd);
    tvedit = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvEdit);
    tvview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvView);




add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i=new Intent(Reminder.this, Addreminder.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
});

       edit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // enter the code for bEditBtn click here
    }
});

      view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // enter the code for bViewBtn click here
    }
    });
}

   }
```

I have also declared the class name in the `manifest.xml` but it does not working

Logcat Log file : 5 lines of last logcat file after clicking the button :

```
    05-15 18:19:25.495: W/AudioFlinger(33): write blocked for 69 msecs, 1245 delayed                
    writes, thread 0xc658
    05-15 18:19:28.964: I/ActivityManager(60): Starting: Intent {         
    act=com.birthdayreminder.REMINDER cmp=com.birthdayreminder/.Reminder } from pid 548
    05-15 18:19:29.409: I/ActivityManager(60): Displayed  
    com.birthdayreminder/.Reminder: +426ms
```

Comment: You checked if you ever enter the case R.id.bAdd?

Comment: Have you set onClick Listener for that imagebutton ?

Comment: check your button id match to bAdd also check logcat

Comment: Double check the names of the two activities written in the intent an the id of the button.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question, but you should avoid generic Exceptions on try-catch, also empty catch blocks.

Comment: Close each case block..

Comment: ya i have kept onclicklistener for all of three buttons ... i also cheked the logcat for any error specification but it does not even showing me the error

Comment: Check with log statement if you are entering on click.

Comment: i have cheked the logcat but when i m clicking to any of the buttons. it does not maintain any log... logcat keep on idle mode or either display othr logging

Comment: Post your entire code of Activity...Try `v.getContext()` in place of `Reminder.this`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check if you have a click listener on you imagebutton, you have declared what to do on click, but if you don't have any listener on the imagebutton, it won't work anyway.
You can try something like this :

```
yourImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Reminder.this, Addreminder.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

After doing this, you must have declared in your XML file the activity

```
<activity android:name="packageName.className" />
```

Finally, check if the new class is working well too but it must be ok!

==================================================================================

You mustn't declare a function or procedure in a function (like you did in onCreate), you can simply do what you do in initialize in your onCreate function like this :

```
package com.birthdayreminder;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Reminder extends Activity {

private ImageButton view;
private ImageButton add;
private ImageButton edit;

private TextView tvadd;
private TextView tvedit;
private TextView tvview;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_reminder);


    // Instantiating Buttons
    view = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bView);
    add = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
    edit = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bEdit);

    // Instantiating Views
    tvadd = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvAdd);
    tvedit = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvEdit);
    tvview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvView);


        // Adding a clickListener on add button
    add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i=new Intent(Reminder.this, Addreminder.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    // Adding a clickListener on edit button
    edit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // enter the code for bEditBtn click here
        }
    });
       // Adding a clickListener on view button
       view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // enter the code for bViewBtn click here
        }
    });
  }

}
```

If you still have a problem, check your XML files, and look if you have well declared your buttons.

Problem Fixed: Never define a function in a function, because everytime you call the first function you'll define again the second function.
What you did which is wrong :

```
onCreate {                  //WRONG VERSION
   bla bla bla bla
   initialisation {
      bla bla bla
   }
}
```

What you have to do :

```
onCreate {                  //GOOD VERSION
   initialisation();
   bla bla bla
}
initialisation {
   bla bla bla 
}
```

you can call a function in a function, but you can't define a function in a function.

Moreover, you never call your initialisation function, you must call it now in your onCreate function or nothing will happen.

Comment: i have done coding in XML FILE ALSO : `<activity
            android:name="com.birthdayreminder.Addreminder"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.birthdayreminder.ADDREMINDER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity> `

Comment: If you start your application with this class, there is no problem, but if it's not the first activity that you wanna see when you start your application : <activity android:name="packageName.className" /> would be efficient and more simple.
Did you do a click listener on your image button as i show you? Or maybe can you show me your code with your imagebutton declaration ?

Comment: i'll edit my answer to correct your code as much as possible, i'll give you that in a min

Comment: copy the code i gave you, you mustn't declare a function or procedure in a function or procedure, because everytime you'll call onCreate, you'll trying to declare again your initialising function. So directly do what you do in initialising in your onCreate function.

Comment: YES :) THNK U VERY VERY MUCH DEAR .... your code worked .. thnx again. can you please tell me what's wrong was their in my code please. so i will not again get in this trouble..please and thanx again for your precious time @Eydolol

Comment: i told you what was wrong in the comment before but i'll write it in my answer by an edit.
Please check the tick at the left of my answer to let the others know what was the good answer.

Answer (score 1):

try using getApplicationContext() in place of Remainder.this

Comment: sry i am new to android development i don't know how to use the 'getApplicationContext()'

Comment: change this     Intent i=new Intent(Reminder.this, Addreminder.class);       as     Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Addreminder.class);

Comment: have you  done this in your 2nd activity   setContentView(R.layout.Addremainder);

Comment: ya i have specified this in my Addreminder class in the `onCreate()` method . and also specify in the menifest.xml file

Answer (score 0):

have you set onClickListener on add button.

```
btnAdd.setOnClickListener(this);
```

also check the

is your `v.getId()` and `case R.id.bAdd:` same?
debug and check that your case R.id.bAdd: is getting executed..

Comment: ya all code as you mention is correct. but after clicking to button it does not give any reaction to the logcat. logcat remains idle

Comment: hav u debugged ur app?..is ur onClick gets called?

Comment: my onClick method doesn't even get called... and no response happening on the logcat when i click to any of the button

Answer (score 0):

Seperately initialize the buttons in the first activity as

```
 Button bAddbutton= (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
    Button bEditBtn= (Button) findViewById(R.id.bEdit);
    Button bViewBtn= (Button) findViewById(R.id.bView);
```

Then add seperate onClick listeners for each button as given below,

```
bAddbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i=new Intent(Reminder.this, Addreminder.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });

    bEditBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // enter the code for bEditBtn click here
                }
            });

    bViewBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // enter the code for bViewBtn click here
                }
            });
```

Comment: same problem ... no output at the logcat

Comment: have you checked and made sure that the button ids are correct?

Comment: ya i have check all id's of button they are matching with each other.

Answer (score 0):

initialize the button and add listener first in oncreate()

Button btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
btnAdd.setOnClickListener(this);